# disabling datasource requirement for reports in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datasource, microsoft-reporting

In VS2008, if you have an existing dataset in your project, you can add that to a new microsoft report (.rdlc file) without HAVING TO provide a datasource of any sort.

In VS2010 however, if you want to either go through the wizard, or add a dataset, you HAVE TO provide a datasource for the report to get its dataset from, is there a way to disable this?

I've found a work around in creating the rdlc in 2008 and just copying and pasting the file to a 2010 project, but that's just ridiculous.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.